# Convincing TypeScript a type can be undefined as well

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion, undefined

It's quite common to have to tell TypeScript some value definitely exists and will not be `undefined`. Almost never is this the other way around though - having to persuade TypeScript into believing it was actually *over*confident in the defined-ness of a type.

Ill-fatedly, I have ran into one such case.

```js
const listA = document.querySelector(...);
const listB = document.querySelector(...);

while (listA.children.length > 0 || listB.children.length > 0) {
  const itemA: HTMLElement | undefined = listA.children[0] as any;
  const itemB: HTMLElement | undefined = listB.children[0] as any;

  // ...
}
```

In this example, the `while` loop continues whenever at least one of both lists still contains elements. This means that if either of the two lists are empty and the other is not, either `itemA` or `itemB` will be `undefined`. TypeScript, however, does not seem to be able to comprehend such things. It seems as though it has its heart set on both variables possessing over an `HTMLElement` and refuses to listen to anyone who says otherwise.

Desperately, I even tried the line

```
const itemA: HTMLElement | undefined = listA.children[0] as any as HTMLElement | undefined;
```

but it was of no use.

Is there any way to get TypeScript to acknowledge the items' potential for being `undefined`?

Comment: document.querySelector's return type is already `Element | null`, as defined in the spec. What are you doing that causes Typescript to not complain that listA and listB are possibly null? See [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gQRgXhgExMArgWwFMwoA6AR10ICcBPAZULkOChGoAoAiUgDy4CUAbgBQoSLETQAQuiw4CxMpRoMmLNpx61BokQHcAFgmYwOUqMlLBjcTNWKlmYAOZRDMAHwwADDAA+-vBIUNLWtvaOzm4e3j4CMADeIjAwAPRpMKTZIgC+QA).

Comment: Enable noUncheckedIndexedAccess.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue without also demonstrating unrelated problems (like indexing into a possibly-`null` list).  That will help us help you without being distracted by stuff you're not asking about.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I'm not exactly sure as to how what I have provided here is *not* a minimal reproducible example. Do you want me to add HTML code for two `div` tags and reference those in the `querySelector` calls?

Comment: @ChrisHeald Ah you seem to have misunderstood. It's not about `listA` and `listB` are possibly `null`, it's about `itemA` and `itemB` possibly being `undefined`.

Comment: The `null` issue is a distraction because your code isn’t an [mre]. If I paste your code as-is into a standalone IDE (like the playground linked above by the other user) then I am immediately confronted with that instead of your problem.

Comment: @jcalz That's weird, because the original code is not actually any different from what I wrote here. VSCode does not complain at all about `querySelector` possibly returning `null` as it does in the playground link you commented. I suppose it's an issue with VSCode then...

Comment:  It sounds like your compiler options are relevant then; the conventional "standard" set is to turn on `--strict` which includes `--strictNullChecks`. If you don't have that enabled then `null` and `undefined` are essentially absorbed into all types, meaning that the compiler doesn't care about them at all.  If you turn on `--strictNullChecks` does it fix your issue and/or fully address the question? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?